# Простое клиент-серверное приложение на андроид

Tags: java, android

Хочу добавить собственную систему self-promotion в свои андроид приложения. Например, чтобы при запуске моих приложений пользователи могли видеть рекламу моих новых приложений. Думаю хранить картинки и рекламный текст на сервере, а при запуске приложения загружать и отображать их в приложении. Что для этого нужно?Раньше никогда не разрабатывал клиент-серверные приложения. Пожалуйста, подскажите в какую сторону копать.

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/269135/

Comment: @And Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно найти сервер для хранения данных, потом реализовать в приложении запросы на на сервер. Для запросов лучше всего подойдет [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) !

Comment: Где найти сервер? Самому создавать или есть готовые решения? Если есть, то сколько они стоят?

Comment: Можно разместить базу данных на хостинге, написать для нее простое API, через которое будете получать необходимые данные. 
Если же требуется хранить и получать только изображения, можно воспользоваться одним из [этих сервисов](https://lifehacker.ru/2013/09/12/luchshie-servisy-dlya-xraneniya-vashix-foto-v-oblake/), у большинства есть свой API через который вы сможете работать с изображениям